QGIS Print Layout layers can't be rotated without the map boundaries also rotating
QGIS 3.38.3 Windows 11 Home
After creating Shapefile layers in a project, I then created a print layout showing the layers.  After inspecting the print layout I saw that I'd achieve a better display for export to a PDF file if I rotated the layer content slightly.  If I rotate the layer data on the canvas, a refresh of the print layout has no effect on the display.  If I rotate the print layout itself, both the data and the map frame rotate.  It seems that the content in the print display can't be rotated without the map frame also rotating.  Do I have to create a new print layout to get the desired result?

Could you add a screenshot showing how you are setting the rotation? If you select the map item in the layout, then right at the top of the Item Properties widget under Main properties, there is a spin box labelled Map rotation which rotates the content inside the map item. Further down, below Position and Size, there is another Rotation setting which rotates the map item itself.

Thanks, Ben W.  That solved the problem.  I was using the 'Rotation' item further down the Item Properties which rotated both map frame and data.
